# MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method share on channel plugins.flutter.io/share)

Tags: flutter, dart, share

i found error when i use `flutter_share: ^1.0.2+1`

```
    MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method share on channel plugins.flutter.io/share)


   E/flutter ( 3361): MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method share on channel plugins.flutter.io/share)
E/flutter ( 3361): #0      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:278:7)
E/flutter ( 3361): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 3361): #1      Share.share (package:share/share.dart:44:20)
E/flutter ( 3361): #2      SignalCard.build.<anonymous closure>
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

i Solve it by `remove` flutter app from my device and `reinstall` via usb or any other Medium

Comment: Dear, I have done twice, thrice but still getting same issue. Thanks.

Comment: @Kamlesh did you got the solution? I am still getting that error

Comment: @Sachin `flutter_share` and `share` packages have discontinued. Now I am using official `share_plus` plugin, you can find it at https://pub.dev/packages/share_plus I hope, this will solve your issue. Thanks.

Comment: @Sachin `flutter_share` and `share` packages have discontinued. Now I am using official `share_plus` plugin, you can find it at https://pub.dev/packages/share_plus I hope, this will solve your issue. Thanks.

Comment: okay @Kamlesh got it

Answer (score 14):

The share plugin works as intended. The error probably appears because the addition of the plugin was followed by hot restart or hot reload rather than full restart. This means the plugin's platform-specific code is not built into the app.

Work around: stop the app and restart it after adding a plugin.

source: https://github.com/flutter/website/pull/1038

Comment: Dear, I have done twice, thrice but still getting same issue. Thanks.

Comment: thank you, i was doing only hot reload and giving error; worked fine after reinstalling the app.

Answer (score 2):

If you use share plugin in web project, this error will appear permanently.
As write [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/55330), you must use [share_plus plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/share_plus)

But this plugin (share_plus), can't share files

```
  /// Share files
  @override
  Future<void> shareFiles(
    List<String> paths, {
    List<String>? mimeTypes,
    String? subject,
    String? text,
    Rect? sharePositionOrigin,
  }) {
    throw UnimplementedError('shareFiles() has not been implemented on Web.');
  }
```

And share message (text + subject) only by mail

```
  // see https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/43838#issuecomment-823551891
  final uri = Uri(
    scheme: 'mailto',
    query: queryParameters.entries
        .map((e) =>
            '${Uri.encodeComponent(e.key)}=${Uri.encodeComponent(e.value)}')
        .join('&'),
  );
```

Answer (score 2):

When you add a plugin to your app which contains native code you have to restart the app in order to be loaded. So hot restart etc. is not enough.

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE: `flutter_share` and `share` packages have discontinued.**

Now I am using official `share_plus` plugin, you can find it at

https://pub.dev/packages/share_plus

I hope, this will solve your issue. Thanks.